# Javamail API javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: Connection reset while reading inbox

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I've written the below java code to read the inbox messages:

```
public void readEMail() {
    try {
        String user = "<<MY_EMAIL_ADDRESS>>";
        String password = "<<MY_PASSWORD>>";

        Properties properties = System.getProperties();
        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);

        Store store = session.getStore("pop3");
        store.connect(MY_HOST_NAME, user, password);

        Folder folder = store.getFolder("inbox");
        if (!folder.exists()) {
            System.out.println("inbox not found");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        folder.open(Folder.READ);

        Message[] msg = folder.getMessages();
        for (int i = 0; i < msg.length; i++) {
            String from = InternetAddress.toString(msg[i].getFrom());
            if (from != null) {
                System.out.println("From: " + from);
            }
            String replyTo = InternetAddress.toString(msg[i].getReplyTo());
            if (replyTo != null) {
                System.out.println("Reply-to: " + replyTo);
            }
            String to = InternetAddress.toString(msg[i].getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO));
            if (to != null) {
                System.out.println("To: " + to);
            }
            String subject = msg[i].getSubject();
            if (subject != null) {
                System.out.println("Subject: " + subject);
            }
            Date sent = msg[i].getSentDate();
            if (sent != null) {
                System.out.println("Sent: " + sent);
            }
            System.out.println("Message : ");
            System.out.println(msg[i].getContent());
        }
        folder.close(true);
        store.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I'm getting AuthenticationFailed Exception on the line

```
store.connect(MY_HOST_NAME,user,password);
```

And if I change my provider from pop3 to imap, I get the exception `javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: AUTHENTICATE failed`

**EDIT**

When using IMAP and setting debug to true, the following is printed in console:

```
DEBUG: JavaMail version 1.5.6
DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: /META-INF/javamail.default.providers
DEBUG: Tables of loaded providers
DEBUG: Providers Listed By Class Name: {com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Oracle], com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle], com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Oracle], com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3s,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore,Oracle], com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Oracle], com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store,Oracle]}
DEBUG: Providers Listed By Protocol: {imaps=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Oracle], imap=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Oracle], smtps=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Oracle], pop3=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store,Oracle], pop3s=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3s,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore,Oracle], smtp=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle]}
DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: /META-INF/javamail.default.address.map
DEBUG: setDebug: JavaMail version 1.5.6
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Oracle]
DEBUG IMAP: mail.imap.fetchsize: 16384
DEBUG IMAP: mail.imap.ignorebodystructuresize: false
DEBUG IMAP: mail.imap.statuscachetimeout: 1000
DEBUG IMAP: mail.imap.appendbuffersize: -1
DEBUG IMAP: mail.imap.minidletime: 10
DEBUG IMAP: closeFoldersOnStoreFailure
DEBUG IMAP: trying to connect to host "blrkeccas.ad.infosys.com", port 143, isSSL false
* OK The Microsoft Exchange IMAP4 service is ready.
A0 CAPABILITY
* CAPABILITY IMAP4 IMAP4rev1 AUTH=NTLM AUTH=GSSAPI AUTH=PLAIN STARTTLS UIDPLUS CHILDREN IDLE NAMESPACE LITERAL+
A0 OK CAPABILITY completed.
DEBUG IMAP: AUTH: NTLM
DEBUG IMAP: AUTH: GSSAPI
DEBUG IMAP: AUTH: PLAIN
DEBUG IMAP: protocolConnect login, host=<<HOST_NAME>>, user=<<USER_NAME>>, password=<non-null>
DEBUG IMAP: AUTHENTICATE PLAIN command trace suppressed
DEBUG IMAP: AUTHENTICATE PLAIN command result: A1 NO AUTHENTICATE failed.
```

And when using POP3, the output is:

```
DEBUG: JavaMail version 1.5.6
DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: /META-INF/javamail.default.providers
DEBUG: Tables of loaded providers
DEBUG: Providers Listed By Class Name: {com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Oracle], com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle], com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Oracle], com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3s,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore,Oracle], com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Oracle], com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store,Oracle]}
DEBUG: Providers Listed By Protocol: {imaps=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Oracle], imap=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Oracle], smtps=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Oracle], pop3=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store,Oracle], pop3s=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3s,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore,Oracle], smtp=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle]}
DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: /META-INF/javamail.default.address.map
DEBUG: setDebug: JavaMail version 1.5.6
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store,Oracle]
DEBUG POP3: mail.pop3.rsetbeforequit: false
DEBUG POP3: mail.pop3.disabletop: false
DEBUG POP3: mail.pop3.forgettopheaders: false
DEBUG POP3: mail.pop3.cachewriteto: false
DEBUG POP3: mail.pop3.filecache.enable: false
DEBUG POP3: mail.pop3.keepmessagecontent: false
DEBUG POP3: mail.pop3.starttls.enable: false
DEBUG POP3: mail.pop3.starttls.required: false
DEBUG POP3: mail.pop3.finalizecleanclose: false
DEBUG POP3: mail.pop3.apop.enable: false
DEBUG POP3: mail.pop3.disablecapa: false
DEBUG POP3: connecting to host <<HOST_NAME>>, port 110, isSSL false
```

Comment: Your code is working fine with `imaps`. I have tested it with gmail.
Are you trying to access `gmail` account?

Comment: No... I'm accessing my corporate email account... But I've verified that my host name, email address and password provided are correct

Comment: I think you should configure your Mail Server, maybe your server not support imap or it's need some changes.

Comment: JavaDoc says `This exception is thrown when the connect method on a Store or Transport object fails due to an authentication failure (e.g., bad user name or password).`
Enable debug to see what exactly happening while establishing connection. `properties.put("mail.debug", "true")`

Comment: [Change Session.getDefaultInstance to Session.getInstance](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#getdefaultinstance).  Also, it's not clear if you're setting any properties, in which case JavaMail will connect without using SSL.  Many mail servers will refuse to accept your password unless it's sent over a secure connection.  Set the property `mail.imap.ssl.enable` to `true`.  If that doesn't help, post the [JavaMail debug output](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug).